# Fixed div positioning

Tags: css, mobile

I'm developing a mobile website that has essentially three `divs` a header, content, and footer. I want the header and footer to be fixed and the content scrollable if there is over flow. Right now my css is:

```
#header{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 8%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    text-height:font-size;
}

#content{
    top: 8%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 0; 
}

#footer{
    height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align:center;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This works perfectly, however in the content I have some text fields and on a mobile device when the keyboard pops up the header and footer also get pushed up making the content field too small. Is there anyway to keep them fixed but not have them get pushed up when entering in text?

Answer (score 1):

You could just hide the footer using JavaScript every time a textfield gains focus, since the fact that the website gets smaller is hard-coded in the operating system (which is responsible for showing the keyboard)

This can be done using jQuery, or for mobile even better (because smaller): zepto.js

Hope that helps

Answer (score -2):

```
#content{
    top: 8%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 15%;
    **width: 100%;**
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 0; 
}
```

Change this highlighted text into px value.
% values adjust the object based on your browser size.

Comment: Changing the width wouldn't do anything to help me. I would have to change the height, and if I make the height a px value instead of % then it wouldn't look right on multiple devices with different screen sizes